# Azure OpenAI - models missing

Tags: azure-openai

Yesterday I have been deploying Azure Open AI resource using Bicep template and it went OK. I was deploying following models:

- gpt-35-turbo-16k version: 0613
- gpt-35-turbo version 0613
- text-embedding-ada-002 version 2

And today I can't see `gpt-35-turbo-16k` at all, and I can't see the `0613` version as well. It's also impossible to choose the version at all for the `gpt-35-turbo`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact there has been internal issue, which made Microsoft to turn off certain model versions. Take a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329186/where-did-gpt-3-5-turbo-0613-and-gpt-3-5-turbo-16k

It seems models 0613 have been restored, at least in US East region.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by the region your created the resource in. Check the regions supported by the model you need and create the model in that region

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue in East US region for gpt-35-turbo-16k, you can use the other regions as mentioned in the document.

Comment: I sort of can - if I want to have all deployment in one region (including embeddings) it's not so obvious. I also wanted 0613 on regular gpt-35-turbo, which (as far as I remember) was not available in any other region of my interest.